# PHP Foreach displaying one set of values multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type

My `foreach` in the PHP/AJAX/JS below is displaying one set of results several times rather than the two results it should a single time each. I have to use a `foreach` to achieve the end result im looking for but this isn't displaying all of the information.

```
$entries = [];
$entries['id'] = get_the_id();
$entries['fname'] = get_field('fname');
$entries['lname'] = get_field('lname');
$entries['custid'] = get_field('customer_id');
$entries['company'] = get_field('company');
$entries['addr1'] = get_field('address_line_1');
$entries['addr2'] = get_field('address_line_2');
$entries['city'] = get_field('city');
$entries['state'] = get_field('state');
$entries['zip'] = get_field('zip');


<script>
function populateFields() {
    alert('Gathering representatives...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form-shipping.php",
        data: <?php foreach($entries as $entry){?>
            {
                "id": <?php echo $entry['id'];?>,
                "fname": <?php echo $entry['fname'];?>,
                "lname": <?php echo $entry['lname'];?>,
                "custid": <?php echo $entry['custid'];?>,
                "company": <?php echo $entry['company'];?>,
                "addr1": <?php echo $entry['addr1'];?>,
                "addr2": <?php echo $entry['addr2'];?>,
                "city": <?php echo $entry['city'];?>,
                "state": <?php echo $entry['state'];?>,
                "zip": <?php echo $entry['zip'];?>,
            } ;
        <?php } ?>
        dataType: 'text';
        success function (){

        }
    });
    //if option value is equal to $ID, echo fields that match $ID
    ...
```

And my results are

```
<script>
    function populateFields() {
        alert('Gathering representatives...')
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "form-shipping.php",
          data: {
                    "id": 136,
                    "fname": John,
                    "lname": Franklin,
                    "custid": 00100120141,
                    "company": Bonetta Inc.,
                    "addr1": 123 Bonetta Ln,
                    "addr2": ,
                    "city": Indianopolis,
                    "state": Indiana,
                    "zip": 1234,
                } ;
                                {
                    "id": 136,
                    "fname": John,
                    "lname": Franklin,
                    "custid": 00100120141,
                    "company": Bonetta Inc.,
                    "addr1": 123 Bonetta Ln,
                    "addr2": ,
                    "city": Indianopolis,
                    "state": Indiana,
                    "zip": 1234,
                } ;
                                {
                    "id": 136,
                    "fname": John,
                    "lname": Franklin,
                    "custid": 00100120141,
                    "company": Bonetta Inc.,
                    "addr1": 123 Bonetta Ln,
                    "addr2": ,
                    "city": Indianopolis,
                    "state": Indiana,
                    "zip": 1234,
                } ;
                                {
                    "id": 136,
                    "fname": John,
                    "lname": Franklin,
                    "custid": 00100120141,
                    "company": Bonetta Inc.,
                    "addr1": 123 Bonetta Ln,
                    "addr2": ,
                    "city": Indianopolis,
                    "state": Indiana,
                    "zip": 1234,
                } ;
                                    {
                    "id": 136,
                    "fname": John,
                    "lname": Franklin,
                    "custid": 00100120141,
                    "company": Bonetta Inc.,
                    "addr1": 123 Bonetta Ln,
                    "addr2": ,
                    "city": Indianopolis,
                    "state": Indiana,
                    "zip": 1234,
                } ;
                                    {
                    "id": 136,
                    "fname": John,
                    "lname": Franklin,
                    "custid": 00100120141,
                    "company": Bonetta Inc.,
                    "addr1": 123 Bonetta Ln,
                    "addr2": ,
                    "city": Indianopolis,
                    "state": Indiana,
                    "zip": 1234,
                } ;
                                        {
                    "id": 136,
                    "fname": John,
                    "lname": Franklin,
                    "custid": 00100120141,
                    "company": Bonetta Inc.,
                    "addr1": 123 Bonetta Ln,
                    "addr2": ,
                    "city": Indianopolis,
                    "state": Indiana,
                    "zip": 1234,
                } ;
                                        {
                    "id": 136,
                    "fname": John,
                    "lname": Franklin,
                    "custid": 00100120141,
                    "company": Bonetta Inc.,
                    "addr1": 123 Bonetta Ln,
                    "addr2": ,
                    "city": Indianopolis,
                    "state": Indiana,
                    "zip": 1234,
                } ;
                                        {
                    "id": 136,
                    "fname": John,
                    "lname": Franklin,
                    "custid": 00100120141,
                    "company": Bonetta Inc.,
                    "addr1": 123 Bonetta Ln,
                    "addr2": ,
                    "city": Indianopolis,
                    "state": Indiana,
                    "zip": 1234,
                } ;
                                    {
                    "id": 136,
                    "fname": John,
                    "lname": Franklin,
                    "custid": 00100120141,
                    "company": Bonetta Inc.,
                    "addr1": 123 Bonetta Ln,
                    "addr2": ,
                    "city": Indianopolis,
                    "state": Indiana,
                    "zip": 1234,
                } ;
            dataType: 'text';
            success function (){

        }
    });
//if option value is equal to $ID, echo fields that match $ID
...
</script>
```

`

Comment: You haven't shown a sample of your array, but based on your `echo` your loop is backwards, should be `foreach($entries as $entry)`

Comment: @AbraCadaver I've edited it to show my array, when I do it the opposite way, it doesn't display anything. I'd attempted that before I posted on here.

Comment: @SpencerPhillips change every `echo $entry` into `echo $entries`.

Comment: (... and yes, as AbraCadaver said it's a bit odd that you named your variable `$entry` which is an array of entries. Should be the other way around for code readability and maintainability.)

Comment: Names matter for someone trying to understand your code, including you when looking at it again months later.  Entry = 1 item, Entries = multiple items.  Using them backwords is a readability bug.

Comment: @cabrerahector I have made the change but now it throws a "Invalid argument supplied" error, and yes, I have since, fixed the naming on the items

Comment: That sounds like a different issue. Please update your code above with the changes you made.

Comment: @cabrerahector it's updated, i've tried it as many ways as I could think.

Comment: You forgot to make one change: now every `<?php echo $entries` should be `<?php echo $entry`. When using `foreach` loops, the variable you usually work with is the one at the right: `$entry` in your case.

Comment: @cabrerahector When I switch those, rather than the array values, it just loads everything with `<br />` tags and displays "Illegal string offset"

Answer (score 0):

If your array example is accurate, you've only created a single-dimensional array. `foreach` would expect to be iterating over a multi-dimensional array.

eg:

```
$entries[0]['id'] = get_the_id();
$entries[0]['fname'] = get_field('fname');
$entries[1]['id'] = get_the_id();
$entries[1]['fname'] = get_field('fname');
$entries[2]['id'] = get_the_id();
$entries[2]['fname'] = get_field('fname');
```

etc

And/or, if you are building a multi-dimensional array (but haven't shown us that you are for brevity), then if you're starting each build with `$entries = [];` you're effectively resetting the array back to empty.

Comment: The issue I run into with adding the [0] or whatever dimension it is, there is supposed to be be 1000 plus posts, that would be way to crowded and destructive on the rest of the code